# How to set RAM limit inside OpenVZ container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, kvm-virtualization, openvz

I had VPS on OpenVZ (*Ubuntu Server 16.04*). 

My hoster made some weird migration and put that container inside KVM. 
So now it looks like I have 8 exabytes of RAM:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       8388608T        436M    8388607T         63M        890M    8388607T
```

But it should be only 2 Gb according to my plan. I've made some tests, and KVM makes the job right: it drops process with OOM after 2gb.

But all mine monitor systems went crazy showing such big number. 
*(And the hoster doesn't want to change anything.)*

So I am wondering, is there a way to limit RAM just being inside that VPS?

Comment: You could ask hoster to disable memory hotplug. This will fix your issue.